# Paperclip Rails Gem Not giving proper URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I setup paperclip to work with my PDF attachments. Currently, when I go to the console and I search Model.certificate.url, I get a URL as such:

```
//bucketname-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/policies/certificates/000/001/163/original/certificate_bc4525d9-8d41-4635-8f26-ba24b0b69037.pdf?1493755437
```

However, I am not able to access this link as there is no HTTP/HTTPS beginning associated with this. If I use Model.certificate.expiring_url, I get the full link with HTTP/HTTPs.

Why is this?

Here are my options in `production.rb`

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    url: ":s3_domain_url",
    path: "/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename",
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
      access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
      secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
      s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration should include the `s3_protocol` option, mentioned in the [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/master/Paperclip/Storage/S3#s3_protocol-instance_method):

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  url: ":s3_domain_url",
  path: "/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename",
  storage: :s3,
  s3_protocol: 'http',
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
    access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
  }
}
```